# PHP pass variable to awk

Tags: php, awk

I'm a new one using PHP. I want to use awk in PHP.
I have a file which is named `a`. The content is:

```
www.b.com * record=600,IN,A,1.2.3.4record=600,IN,A,5.6.7.8
www.1.com u record=600,IN,A,1.2.3.4
www.1.com w record=600,IN,A,1.2.3.4
```

Now I use PHP to handle it.

```
<?php


        $dn = "www.1.com";

        $hello = shell_exec("awk '{ if ( $1==".$dn.")print $1}' a") ;
        echo $hello;
?>
```

It doesn't work — can you tell me why?
If I use this other way, it does work.

```
$hello = shell_exec("awk '{ if ( $1==\"www.b.com\")print $1}' a") ;
```

Comment: learn to debug/trace: `echo "awk '{ if ( $1==".$dn.")print $1}' a";`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`awk` sees `$dn` as a string literal, so you need to quote the string inside `awk`, which is what you did in your test example:

```
$dn = "www.1.com";

$hello = shell_exec("awk '{ if ( $1==\"".$dn."\")print $1}' a") ;
// ---------------------------------^^^-------^^^
// Surround in escaped double quotes...
echo $hello;
```

If the string `$dn` is to be sourced from any kind of user or browser input, be sure to properly escape it with [`escapeshellarg()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) or [`escapeshellcmd()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) first. Since `escapeshellarg()` adds single quotes, that probably isn't useful here, but `escapeshellcmd()` which is normally used to escape the entire command, could at least escape any internal quotes or other bad characters that might come in `$dn`.